# JAVA / Processing - Instantiating multiple of same objects - Only displays one out of 5

Tags: java, processing

I have a problem regarding drawing multiple of the same objects. They end on top of each other, and their "Object values" even get added together e.g. if a zombie has "2" movement value and there is added 2 into the current level. Then when zombies are moved, they move "4" each. This does not happen if two different objects are moved e.g. Zombie and Dragon. I have created the following code based on my project - for a simpler overview. However, the behavior is the same.

It should be mentioned the objects of the same type have the same "HashCode". I have also made comments and println to help figure out the problem. Each of the 5 objects have different position (When set). However, they are rendered on top of each other and merged (Movement).

```
EnemyDatabase enemyDatabase;
ArrayList<Enemy> enemiesInlevel = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  enemyDatabase = new EnemyDatabase();

  enemyDatabase.enemies.add(new Enemy("Zombie", 3));

  //If dragon is added - Then it can draw both - But only once
  //enemyDatabase.enemies.add(new Enemy("Dragon", 10));

  //Add 10 zombies to the level
  for(int i=0; i< 5;i++)
  {
    //5 Zombies are created and succesfully added to the database
    enemiesInlevel.add(enemyDatabase.enemies.get((int)random(0, enemyDatabase.enemies.size())));;    
  }

  for(int i=0; i<enemiesInlevel.size();i++)
  {
    //Sets the position of all 5 - Gives random position
    Enemy enemy = enemiesInlevel.get(i);
    enemy.SetPosition();
  }
}

void draw()
{
   background(255, 200, 0);

   //Draw 5 enemies - Of index 0 (Zombie)
   for(int i=0; i<enemiesInlevel.size();i++)
   {
     Enemy tempEnemy = enemiesInlevel.get(i);
     tempEnemy.draw();
     //It runs 5 times - print returns 5 total objects in enemiesInlevel
   }
}

class EnemyDatabase
{
  ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
}

class Enemy
{
  String enemyName;
  int enemyHealth;
  PVector enemyPosition;

  public Enemy(String name, int hp)
  {
    enemyName = name;
    enemyHealth = hp;
  }

  public void SetPosition()
  {
    enemyPosition = new PVector(random(0, width), random(0, height));
    //Each of the objects has a random position
    println(enemyPosition);
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    rect(enemyPosition.x, enemyPosition.y, 25, 25);
  }
}
```

UPDATE
Here is an image of the problem

[image: Image of problem]

As the image shows from the output in the image line: The enemies have different positions when added to the array (5 different enemies) However, as the image shows, it still only displays one - And this happens because all of the sudden the positions is the same. I even tried to give a "Random position" in the "DrawImage" all of the enemies still end up having the same position

Hope you guys can figure it out. I certainly have a hard time - I usually don't work in processing Thank you

Comment: Your question is pretty vague and could benefit from showing more code, but a random stab in the dark would be:

`enemiesInlevel.add(enemyDatabase.enemies.get((int)random(0, enemyDatabase.enemies.size())));;`

At this line it may be that you're adding the same object to the array 5 times, causing you to set /all/ of their properties whenever you try to set one of their properties.

Comment: That is the whole code. For clarification "When i add the enemies to the enemies list based on the "Enemy object"" they have unique positions. However, when draw them, they have the same position

Comment: Here is an image of the problem                                                                                                                         
https://gyazo.com/4202f04b2d5d8765e9653cc9066f2964

As the image shows from the output in the image line: The enemies have different positions when added to the array (5 different enemies)

However, as the image shows, it still only displays one - And this happens because all of the sudden the positions is the same.

I even tried to give a "Random position" in the "DrawImage"  all of the enemies still end up having the same position.

Comment: I may be playing the devil's advocate here, but have you tested your `random` method to see that it doesn't return the same value each time it's called?

Comment: Yes I have, and it returns random numbers. I have recently attached an image into the original post, which shows the random positions in the console. But that once using the "Draw" method, the positions are the same. It is like the objects get merged together once rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DrSatan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611065/java-processing-instantiating-multiple-of-same-objects-only-displays-one-o#comment82180444_47611065) is correct. You're only ever adding a single `Enemy` to your `EnemiesDatabase`. So when you select 5 random enemies, you're really just selecting the same enemy 5 times.

It might look like they have different positions in your print statements, but that's because you're printing out the position every time you set it. You're setting it five times, but only the last position really counts for anything.

In other words, you're taking a single instance of `Enemy`, moving it around the screen 5 times, and printing out the position each time. But then when you draw it, only the last position you moved it to is what you see.

You need to refactor your code so you add more enemies to your `EnemyDatabase`, but please note that you're going to have similar problems no matter how many enemies are in your `EnemyDatabsae`, because you don't have any logic that makes sure you don't select the same instance twice. Even if you had 100 enemies in your database, nothing is stopping your random function from selecting the same enemy 5 times.

If I were you, I'd rethink my design. I don't really see the reason to have a separate `EnemyDatabase` class at all. Maybe just create a function that adds X random enemies to the level, where X is a parameter? That's up to you, but your fundamental problem here is that you only have a single instance of `Enemy`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for Clarification. I ended up keeping the database, so I can add multiple different enemy types at the beginning and then later on copying them when i need them in a specific. Works like a charm now.